# How can i find limit points for infinite set in this topology?

Tags: general-topology

How can I prove that every infinite set has a limit point in this topology :
The set $\Bbb R$ with the topology generated by the base $\{[n,r) : n\text{ is an integer and }r\text{ is a real number}\}$ .

Comment: A limit point of $A$ is (as usual) a point $p$ such that every neighbourhood of $p$ contains a point $a \in A,\: a \neq p$? Then show more, show that every nonempty set has a limit point.

Comment: In addition to adding context and efforts, the Question could stand to be rephrased to make it clear whether the basis open sets $[n,r)$ entail only cases $n < r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $n$ is an integer such that the infinite set $S$ has a point $s$ in $[n,n+1)$, then try to show that any point $x\in(s,n+1)$ is a limit point of $S$.

Comment: @Kmath: You can accept my answer if you find it helpful. Just click on the check mark on the left.